# How do you solve this R poisson distribution problem?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, poisson

Here is my attempt at this problem:
Consider a restaurant that is open from 3pm to 11PM (i.e., 6 hours) each day. Now assume the number of guests arriving at the restaurant each hour follows a discrete (Poisson) distribution with rate lambda λ=10 guests per hour. Now assume that the restaurant can service up to 16 guests per hour. ( Please note that the time of arrival of each guests is not recorded, so we just assume that up to 16 guests are serviced every hour, irrespective of when they arrive in within that hour.). Any guests which have not been served food in a given hour are added to the number of guests arriving in the next hour (eg, if 20 customers arrive in a given hour, then 4 of them will need to wait until the next hour to get food served. At the end of the day, any queue of customers waiting to get food is served cleared, so the next day starts with only the guests arriving in the first hour of when the restaurant reopens.

1. Write a function called waiting_guests that simulates a day at the restaurant. The function needs to have the following arguments:

lambda: the rate of guests per hour arriving at the restaurant

Guests: the number of Guests that can be served in each hour.

hours: the number of hours the restaurant is open for the day.
The function should return a vector that gives the number of guests that are still waiting for to be served food the end of each hour.

Show code for the function as well as output from running the function to simulate a day at the restaurant. For the simulation of a day at the restaurant, use all of the relevant information provided above.
I also want to simulate 5000 days at the restaurant which I haven't tried yet.

Below is what I think is the code without the 5000 days simulation

```
# required function with 3 arguments
waiting_guests <- function(lambda, guests, hours) {
    # null vector vec
    vec <- c()
    # initialize values as in the code
    current_guests <- 0
    remaining_guests <- 0
    # while loop with condition hours != 0
    while (hours != 0) {
        # update values
        current_guests <- remaining_guests + lambda
        remaining_guests <- current_guests - guests
        # append values based on condition
        if (remaining_guests > 0) {
            vec <- append(vec, remaining_guests)
        } else {
            vec <- append(vec, 0);
        }
        # update hours
        hours <- hours-1;
    }
    # return the vector
    return (vec)
}

answer <- waiting_guests(10,16,8) 
print(answer)
```

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simulate the Poisson distribution in your function.  Instead of adding lambda use the `rpois()` function: `current_guests <- remaining_guests + rpois(1, lambda)`.

```
waiting_guests <- function(lambda, guests, hours) {
   # null vector vec
   vec <- c()
   # initialize values as in the code
   current_guests <- 0
   remaining_guests <- 0
   # while loop with condition hours != 0
   while (hours != 0) {
      # update values
      current_guests <- remaining_guests + rpois(1, lambda)
      remaining_guests <- max( current_guests - guests, 0)
      print(paste(current_guests, remaining_guests))
         vec <- c(vec, remaining_guests)
      #update hours
      hours <- hours-1;
   }
   # return the vector
   return (vec)
}

answer <- waiting_guests(10,16,8) 
print(answer)
```

It is a rare event that Poisson distribution will exceed 16 with a lambda of 10.

Comment: When I adjusted it to lambda=3 and customers = 4 and kept hours = 8 the same, sometimes when I ran the code your wrote, there is an error

Comment: Error in vector() <- append(vector, remaining_customers) : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Comment: Also how would you simulate 5000 days using the above code?

Comment: The phrase "vector()" does not appear in the code snippet above so I don't know where that error statement is coming from.  Try clearing out your environment.  To simulate the 5000 days, I would wrap the calling statement in a `lapply` , `lapply(1:5000, function(i) {waiting_guests(14,16,8)})` and then deal with the list of results.

Comment: why 14?. Just a typo?

Comment: Yes, typo to test the number of excess per hour

Comment: Also when I run the adjusted code it comes up with this, which I find unsual:

Comment: this is without setting the seed

Comment: I left in a print statement in the function to print out the current guests and reminding guests.  Resetting the seed is only required if you want reproducible results from run to run.  There is a random default seed set with the start-up of the R session.

Comment: but why is the printed outcome specifically formatted like this though:

Comment: [1] "19 9"
[1] "23 13"
[1] "33 23"
[1] "37 27"
[1] "50 40"
[1] "58 48"
[1] "62 52"
[1] "64 54"
[1]  9 13 23 27 40 48 52 54